# How to load a video using a string from a database?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, video

I've got a website where I want to be able to generate a list of videos available on my server. Once that user selects a video, it would take them to another page where it plays the video. So far, I've got no errors on either of the pages, but nothing is showing up either :(

Here's the code for my pages:

word.aspx

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
    DataFile="~/App_Data/webvideos.mdb" SelectCommand="SELECT TOP 5 * FROM [Videos] WHERE ID=@ID AND Program LIKE 'Word'">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="ID" QueryStringField="ID" />
    </SelectParameters>
    </asp:AccessDataSource>

    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" RepeatColumns="5">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="VidLink1" runat="server" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl='<%# "VideoPlayer.aspx?ID=" & Eval("ID") %>' >
                    <asp:Image ID="VidThumb" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "videos/TraningVideos/Thumbnails" & Eval("Thumbnail") %>'  /></asp:HyperLink>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

And here's VideoPlayer.aspx:

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="~/App_Data/webvideos.mdb"
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Video WHERE ID=@ID" >
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="ID" QueryStringField="ID" />                    
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:AccessDataSource>
```

'
          width="450" height="380">
          ' />

```
      <param name="autostart" value="false" />
      <param name="controller" value="true" />
    </object>

<ASPNetFlashVideo:FlashVideo ID="FlashVideo1" runat="server" VideoURL="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=okHuuMbIg1E">
</ASPNetFlashVideo:FlashVideo>

<ASPNetFlashVideo:FlashVideo ID="FlashVideo2" runat="server" VideoURL='<%# "~/videos/TrainingVideos/" & Eval("Filename") %>'>
</ASPNetFlashVideo:FlashVideo>
```

As you can see, I've even tried using a regular youtube link for the ASPNetFlashVideo control that I've been able to add, and it hasn't been working either. Any ideas?

Comment: you realize that url you're using returns a full-blown html page? You'd proably want to use a direct link to the .flv underlying that video page.

Comment: I assume you are talking about where I linked to a youtube video. Fair enough. My main question is about playing a video from my web server. I tried using the YouTube link to see if that would work with the ASPNetFlashVideo control. It doesn't. Also, it apparently does work with the object control. I tried it. So it would be great if I were looking for a youtube video, but I'm not.